# Get total number of conversions from Facebook Ads Insight api

Tags: facebook, ads

I would like to get the total number of conversions that occurred for each ad per day for the specified period of time. Something like:

```
2023-01-01 Ad123 5
2023-01-02 Ad123 2
etc
```

The sum of conversions should be the same number that is shown in the ads manager ad table, in the "results" column, for the same period of time.

After reading the docs I still don't understand few things:

- Is there a way to get a scalar number of conversions for given ad in each day? Right now it seems that I would need to sum all the actions listed in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/ - keeping in mind that some of the actions are aggregating results from other (start_trial_total contains numbers from start_trial_website etc.)?
- Why I am missing the "conversion_values" in the response? Is it possible that it will contain the number of conversions that I am looking for? The field is not described at all - ot else, it has the same documentation as other fields, so it's hard to know what to expect.

Currently I use below query which gives me the attached result:

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/insights?fields=ad_id%2Caccount_currency%2Cclicks%2Cspend%2Cimpressions%2Ccost_per_conversion%2Cconversions%2Cconversion_values&action_breakdowns=action_type&action_attribution_windows=1d_click%2C7d_click%2C1d_view&action_report_time=conversion&date_preset=last_90d&time_increment=1&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "read_insights",
      "ads_read",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "app_id": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {
    "fields": "ad_id,account_currency,clicks,spend,impressions,cost_per_conversion,conversions,conversion_values",
    "action_breakdowns": "action_type",
    "action_attribution_windows": "1d_click,7d_click,1d_view",
    "action_report_time": "conversion",
    "date_preset": "last_90d",
    "time_increment": "1"
  }
- POST Parameters


  {}
==== Response
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "ad_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "account_currency": "PLN",
        "clicks": "121",
        "spend": "59.8",
        "impressions": "4715",
        "cost_per_conversion": [
          {
            "action_type": "start_trial_website",
            "value": "59.8",
            "1d_click": "59.8",
            "7d_click": "59.8"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "start_trial_total",
            "value": "59.8",
            "1d_click": "59.8",
            "7d_click": "59.8"
          }
        ],
        "conversions": [
          {
            "action_type": "start_trial_website",
            "value": "1",
            "1d_click": "1",
            "7d_click": "1"
          },
          {
            "action_type": "start_trial_total",
            "value": "1",
            "1d_click": "1",
            "7d_click": "1"
          }
        ],
        "date_start": "2023-03-30",
        "date_stop": "2023-03-30"
      },
    "paging": "--sanitized--"
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2Finsights%3Ffields%3Dad_id%2Caccount_currency%2Cclicks%2Cspend%2Cimpressions%2Ccost_per_conversion%2Cconversions%2Cconversion_values%26action_breakdowns%3Daction_type%26action_attribution_windows%3D1d_click%2C7d_click%2C1d_view%26action_report_time%3Dconversion%26date_preset%3Dlast_90d%26time_increment%3D1&version=v17.0
```